# O(.) Running time of the following algorithm

Tags: algorithm

What's the bigOh running time of the following algorithm (psuedocode form):

```
for i = 1,2,...,n do

  for j = i+1, i+2, ... n do 

    Add up array entries A[i] through A[j]

    Store the result in B[i,j]

  end for

end for
```

Calculating it myself I thought the nested for loop would result in a worst case of O(n^2), how ever I am unsure of the Adding and Storing worst case complexity.

Thanks

Comment: it depends on how they are implemented.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It's usually safe to assume that peeks and pokes on *arrays* take `O(1)` time.

Comment: I guess he meant to implement the calculation as B[i,j] = B[i,j-1]+A[j].  That is faster.

Answer (score 1):

The loop on `i` is n iterations.
The loop on `j` is close to n/2 iterations on average.
The sum of the `A[k]` is over n/3 terms on average

Therefore you need around (n^3)/6 additions.  That is O(n^3).

But if you keep a running total of A[i]+...+A[j] in your loop on `j`, or use previously computed values of `B[i,j]`, you can bring it down to O(n^2).

The loop on `j` uses n-1 iterations and goes down to 0.  And the average of n successive numbers is the average of the 2 extremes,  That is (n-1 + 0)/2.  Almost n/2.

The length of the sum is more difficult to explain.  It is a weighted average with more weight on small numbers than large ones.  The resulting factor 1/3 isn't important anyway.

Comment: Why is j n/2 on average, and the sum n/3?